# multer file without extension

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, multer

at the moment i have this:

```
  var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

router.post('/registo',upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
```

but the file extension for the file passed is not saved, and multer give it a random name, so i saw something like this to correct that problem:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
    });
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });



router.post('/registo',upload, function (req, res) {
```

but with that i get a error: connection refused and i don't know why that happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i upload a file using multer.
node code

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var router = express.Router();
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});


mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1/obi');
router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function (req, res) {
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    var path = req.files[0].path
    var path_name = req.files[0].originalname
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: path_name
    });
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(writestream);
    writestream.on('close', function (file) {
        res.json(file.filename + 'Written To DB');
        fs.unlink(req.files[0].path, function () {
            res.json({id: file._id, message: "success"});
        });
    });
})
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: do i need Grid?

Comment: well my code was working with the first logic, when i want change filename with the 2 logic it doesnt work :(

Comment: yes , gridfs-stream is used  to store and read files from mongodb.

Comment: you know how i can get the image to display on client angular side?

Comment: that doesn't work friend can i talk with you on chat»?

Comment: don't have, facebook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135315/discussion-between-shekhar-tyagi-and-filipe-costa).

Comment: still there Shekhar?

Comment: Yes, here      i am here

Comment: originalname, thank you sir, you really are a hero :)